# Tension in rope between falling objects

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, string

I got a mass m connected with a rope to a mass 2m which is centered directly underneat it. The masses are falling with a constant speed v. Would it be correct to say that the tension in the string is equal to 3/2mg?

[image]

Assume that air-resistance is neglectable.

F=ma

T + T = (m+2m)g,
2T = 3mg,
T = 3/2mg

or would the tension be equal to 0 since the relative velocity is equal to 0?

Comment: If the masses are falling at constant speed $v$ in Earth gravity, then there needs to be an additional force which you have not specified. The answer will change depending on which of the bodies this force acts on.

Comment: Note also that you can enclose maths inside `$ ... $` and `$$ ... $$` signs to get better formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A free body diagram on the $2m$ mass would have $2mg$ down and $T$ up. This would give a Newton's 2nd Law equation, assuming up to be the positive vertical direction, of $$T-2mg=2ma_{2v}$$.
The $m$ mass free-body diagram would yield two downward forces, $T$ and $mg$ with a Newton's 2nd Law equation of 
$$-T-mg=ma_{1v},$$
assuming the tension magnitude in the rope is the same throughout the rope.

Your statement of constant velocity means that both accelerations must be zero. With that we have $$T=2mg$$ from the first equation $$ T=mg$$ from the second. This is clearly an impossible situation unless there are some forces on the masses which are not accounted for.

If they fall with equal and constant acceleration, then we can write $$T-2mg = 2\left(-T-mg\right)$$
$$3T=0$$ and there is no tension in the rope.

Comment: I think it is worthwhile to note that in the case of constant acceleration, $T=0$ follows immediately from the [equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle#The_Einstein_equivalence_principle), since two non-accelerating (say stationary) masses floating in space don't support a tension in a rope connecting them.

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs Seeing the consistency that $T=0 $ in a variety of analyses is useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to see Emilio's argument is to consider both blocks and the rope as one system. With no external force on the system but gravity, the whole system has to fall with acceleration of g. Hence, there can be no tension in the string.